# A general equation for Pythagorean triples of rational numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This question was asked by a friend of mine and I have no idea how to proceed. I am looking for a general solution for the equation $p^2+q^2=r^2$ where $p,q,r$ are rational numbers.

PS: I am not looking for such trivial solutions which can be constructed by Pythagorean triples, e.g., $\frac{6^2}{15^2}+\frac{8^2}{15^2}=\frac{2^2}{3^2}$

Comment: There are no other rational solutions than those you call "trivial"! if $p^2+q^2=r^2$, multiplying by the common denominator gives an equation in integers $P^2+Q^2=R^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no other rational solutions than those based on the Pythagorian triples.

If $$p^2 +q^2 =r^2,$$ or $$\left(\frac{P'}{P''}\right)^2+\left(\frac{Q'}{Q''}\right)^2=\left(\frac{R'}{R''}\right)^2,$$ multiplying by the common denominator gives an equation in integers $$\left(P'Q''R''\right)^2+\left(P''Q'R''\right)^2=\left(P''Q''R'\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem.** If $p, q > 0$ are (rational) integers such that 
$$x := p^{2} - q^{2},$$
$$y := 2pq,$$
$$z := p^{2} + q^{2},$$
$$p+q \equiv 1\ \ (mod\ \ 2),$$
$$p > q,$$
$$(p, q) = 1,$$
then the triple 
$(x, y, z)$
is a solution of the Diophantine equation
$x^{2} + y^{2} = z^{2}.$

In other words, the triples $(x, y, z)$ so generated are primitive (in the sense that $(x, y, z) = 1$) solutions of the equation $x^{2} + y^{2} = z^{2}$.

Indeed, one can find this theorem or its equivalents in many elementary number theory texts. For instance, the famous number theory book of Hardy and Wright.

Comment: As you all love to write a simple solution of the equations. As well! Write decision diofantovy equation:  $x^2+y^2=az^2$ Coefficient $a$ - a whole, and under what its values solution there?

Answer (score 0):

In General formula generic for Pythagorean triples looks a little different.

$$x^2+y^2=az^2$$

If the number can be represented as a sum of squares.  $a=t^2+k^2$

The solution has the form:

$$x=-tp^2+2kps+ts^2$$

$$y=kp^2+2tps-ks^2$$

$$z=p^2+s^2$$

All numbers can be any character.