# Rational distance problem for unit square in 3D

Tags: number-theory, metric-spaces, diophantine-equations

Given a unit square lying on XY plane with center at the origin and we search the whole of 3D space, will we able to find points that are at rational distances (Euclidean metric) from all 4 vertices of the square? If "yes", are there infinitely many such points in 3D space?

I understand, the basic (and still open) form of the question asks for a point on the XY plane that is at rational distances from all 4 vertices.

Note: one could just push the envelope a bit and ask if we search in a higher dimensional (>3) space in which the unit square lies on the x y plane, whether there are points that are at rational euclidean distances from all 4 vertices.

Comment: Interesting problem. I suspect that this discussion could be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880419/a-general-equation-for-pythagorean-triples-of-rational-numbers

Comment: P.S. We could easily answer (affirmatively, for infinitely many points) by assuming another distance that is not the Euclidean one, such as the taxicab metric.

Comment: thanks. i actually meant the euclidean metric. shall edit.

Comment: The answer is unknown as of 2011. See this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379191/simplified-rational-distance-problem#:~:text=It%20is%20not%20known%20whether,each%20of%20the%20four%20corners.) for more details.

Comment: thanks. that doc says the answer is unknown if we search for points *on the same plane as the unit square* (and proves that there is no point on the boundary of the unit square that meets the rational distance requirement) but the present question asks about points in the 3d space.

Comment: You probably wanted the point to have rational coordinates, too. Otherwise an answer in 3D is trivial.

Comment: actually, i hadn't thought of the point necessarily having rational coordinates. as you observe such a requirement could result in more interesting possibilities that i hadn't anticipated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corners of the square, as points in space, are at $$(x,y,z)=(\pm \frac12, \pm \frac12,0)$$ Consider the points of form $$P_n=(x,y,z)=(0,0,\sqrt{n^2-\frac12})$$ Then $P_n$ is at distance $n$ from each corner of the square.

**Added later:** OP has asked for such points not on the $z$ axis. The following construction gives an infinite collection of points which lie directly over the midpoint of a side of the square. We describe them in terms of the square with corners $(\pm a,\pm a)$ where $a$ is to be chosen later. One could rescale to the desired unit square centered at the origin.

To begin with, choose any Pythagorean triple of form $(2a,b,c)$ for which $a>b.$ Then define $P$ as the point $(a,0,\sqrt{b^2-a^2})$ One can check that the distance from P to either square vertex $(+a,\pm a,0)$ is $b,$ while the distance from $P$ to the other square vertices $(-a,\pm a,0)$ is $c.$

Comment: marking the question as answered. just in case there are points (maybe infinitely many of them) that do not lie on the z axis and satisfy the requirement, could something be said about them as well?

Comment: @NandakumarR I have found a collection of points not on the z axis having the desired distance to vertices property, see the edit on my answer.